# How to extract all variables from file

Tags: regex, awk, sed, grep

I have a file with the following format:

```
text${v1}text${v2}etc
```

How do I extract all variables names from it using bash?

Expected output is: `v1` `v2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using simple `grep + sed`:

```bash
grep -o '\${[^}]*}' file | sed -E 's/^\${|}$//g'

v1
v2


Here:

- `grep` matches and prints `${...}` strings
- `sed` removes `\${` and `}` from output
```

Comment: I have the following error when try:
`sed: -e expression #1, char 12: Invalid content of \{\}`

Comment: It should work as I tested before posting. Try calling curly braces like I escaped $

Answer (score 6):

***1st solution:*** Within single GNU `awk` you could try following code. Written and tested with shown samples only. Simple explanation would be, setting RS(record separator) as `\\${[^}]*}` and then in main program substituting values like `${` and `}` from RT and printing only required values as per requirement.

```
awk -v RS='\\${[^}]*}' 'RT{gsub(/^\${|}$/,"",RT);print RT}'  Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** With any `awk` please try following `awk` code.

```
awk '
{
  while(match($0,/\${[^}]*}/)){
    print substr($0,RSTART+2,RLENGTH-3)
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `sed`

```
sed -E 's/[^$]*\$\{([^}]*)}|[[:alpha:] ]+$/\1 /g' input_file
v1 v2
```

Answer (score 4):

An alternative with grep and `-P` to enable  Perl-compatible regular expressions:

```
grep -oP '\${\K[^}]*(?=})' file
```

The pattern matches:

- `\$` Match `$`
- `{` Match literally
- `\K` Forget what is matched until now
- `[^}]*` Match optional repetitions of any char except `}`
- `(?=})` Positive lookahead, assert `}` to the right

Output

```
v1
v2
```

---

Or using `gnu awk` with a capture group in the regex `([^}]*)` and print that group 1 value using `a[1]` (same looping mechanism as the answer of @RavinderSingh13)

```
awk '
{
  while(match($0,/\${([^}]*)}/, a)){
    print a[1]
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
}
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> echo 'text${v1}text${v2}etc' | 
>
> mawk 'gsub(OFS"+", __, $!(NF = NF)) + \
>       gsub("^"(__) "|"(__)"$", _)^_ + gsub(__," /\f\b\b/ ")' \
>                                             __='\300'                                    \
>   FS='(^[^$}{]*)?[$][{]|[}][^}{$]*|[\301]+' OFS='\301'
> ```

```
v1 /
  / v2
```